# Flickering animations on scaling in safari browser

Tags: next.js, safari, tailwind-css, transform, framer-motion

The animations of scaling the project card component when the elements are scrolled and they're scaling up they tend to flicker in safari browser until they're scaled till desired width and height

i am using nextjs and tailwind css code is as follows let me know if more of my code is needed to reach desire solution
i have also tried few of the solutions such as

```
transformStyle: 'preserve-3d',
        backfaceVisibility: 'hidden',
        willChange: 'transform',
```

```
const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({
    target: ref,
    offset: ["0 1", "1.33 1.2"],
  });
  const scaleprogress = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 1], [0.7, 1]);
  return (
    <motion.div
      ref={ref}
      style={{
        scale: scaleprogress,
        transition: "transform 0.2s",
        transformStyle: 'preserve-3d',
        backfaceVisibility: 'hidden',
        willChange: 'transform',
      }}
      className='sticky top-[8.3rem] group mb-3 sm:mb-8 md:mb-8 last:mb-0 md:top-[9rem]'
    >
      <section className="bg-gray-100 max-w-[42rem]  mb-4 border ml-4 border-black/5 md:overflow-hidden sm:pr-8 md:pr-8 relative md:h-[25rem] hover:bg-gray-200 transition md:group-even:pl-8 dark:text-white dark:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:bg-gray-500 rounded-2xl shadow-2xl">
        <Image
          className="relative rounded-xl top-[-9px] md:top-8 md:-right-[6rem] w-[24.25rem] shadow-2xl md:absolute transition   
          md:group-even:right-[initial] 
          md:group-even:-left-[6rem]
          md:group-hover:-translate-x-3 
          md:group-hover:translate-y-3 
          md:group-hover:-rotate-2 

          md:group-hover:scale-[1.05]
          md:group-even:group-hover:translate-x-3 
          md:group-even:group-hover:translate-y-3 
          md:group-even:group-hover:rotate-2"
          src={imageUrl}
          alt={title}
          quality={95}
        />
        <div className="pt-4 pb-7 px-5 md:pl-10 md:pt-10 md:pr-2 md:max-w-[50%] flex flex-col h-full md:group-even:ml-[18rem]">
        <div className="flex flex-row">
            <h3 className="text-2xl font-semibold">{title}</h3>
            <Link href={githublink} target="__blank" className=' bg-black/[0.7] ml-2 mt-1 px-2 py-1  rounded-full text-white  dark:text-white/70'>
              <BsGithub className="h-5 w-5"/>
            </Link>
            <Link  href={previewlink} target="__blank" className=' bg-black/[0.7] ml-2 mt-1 px-2 py-1  rounded-full text-white  dark:text-white/70 '>
              <BsLink45Deg className="h-5 w-5"/>
            </Link>
        </div>
        <p className="project-status-content-wrapper my-2 text-xs rounded px-2 py-2 bg-black/[0.7] text-white w-fit hover:bg-zinc-800 dark:hover:bg-slate-600">{status}</p>  
          <p className="mt-2 leading-relaxed text-gray-700 text-ellipsis dark:text-white/70">
            {description}
          </p>
          <ul className="flex flex-wrap mt-4 gap-2 sm:mt-auto">
            {tags.map((tag, index) => (
              <li
                className="bg-black/[0.7] px-3 py-1 text-[0.7rem] uppercase tracking-wider text-white rounded-full dark:text-white/70"
                key={index}
              >
                {tag}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </section>
    </motion.div>
  );
}
```